# IIS 7 cannot log into Sql Server Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, iis-7

I have an IIS 7 application that uses a domain login. (basic settings, connect as)

The application would log in as the server name at first until I set the application in it's own application pool.

Now the application gets the read data from a gridview but when I attempt to get the detailsview with edit permission it fails.

I had the database set to accept the machine as a read/write (and this worked) but I can't use this solution being the application could move to a different machine and I want it to use a specific set of credentials.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the account of the application pool to my user

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

in the above tutorial there is a section: Configuring IIS Application Pool Identities

just set it to 'custom account' instead of a default user.

Now I can use ssip access from the machine to my db for read/write